# Autosize 2 divs from columns to rows while keeping full width

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to autosize a 2-column div so that the following are true:

Each column autosizes to ~50% of display width.
Each column has a min-width of ~200px.
When either/both columns are less than min-width, drop the right div directly underneath the left div and autosize both divs to full width of display.

The idea is that desktops and tables (400px and wider) will display 2 columns:

```
Width >= 400px
+-------+-------+
|  50%  |  50%  |
+-------+-------+
  div1    div2
```

Smaller displays will display 2 rows:

```
Width < 400px
+---------------+
|     100%      |  div1
+---------------+
|     100%      |  div2
+---------------+
```

Comment: You want to do this in CSS directly, or are you open to a JS solution?

Comment: I was hoping to use CSS. A class for div1, div2 and probably their parent container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure CSS** Solution:

CSS:

```
html, body, .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f0f;
    background-color: #0ff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .content {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
     }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div><!--
    --><div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/LUBpF/1/

Comment: Wow! I wasn't sure it was even possible. That's neat. Thank you Arbel!